# By scrolling the table the text sticks to background

Tags: html, css

Here is my code: (some parts are unnecessary, I know, but let's assume I need need them)

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #viewcss {
    color: #00f
  }
  
  .block {
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    height: 80%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#a9a8a8 3%, #222222 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    margin-top: 2%;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  
  table {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 1%;
  }
  
  td {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #tab1 {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  .center {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block"> <a style="-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;font-size:25px;">Consuntivo</a></br> <a style="font-size:50px;">4336</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <a style="font-size:25px;"></a>
      </br><a>Feed prog:</a><br>
      <a></a><br> <a>Spindle speed:</a><br>
      <a></a>
    </div>
    <div class="block" ; id="tab1">
      <table class="center">
        <tr>
          <td style="-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;font-size:25px;">Carrelli:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>444</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>555</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtKJa.png)
is: how can I resolve text sticking to background while scrolling the table? I've tryed many things, but it only works if I delete this line: `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#a9a8a8 3%, #222222 100%);`. Sadly, I need it to be able to make the text transparent yet still visible

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#a9a8a8 3%, #222222 100%);
```

with

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#a9a8a8 0%, #222222 100%);
```